# Coincidence of two $\tau$-additive measures

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I'm struggling to prove the following Lemma from V.I. Bogachev, Measure Theory 2:

> Let two $\tau$-additive measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on a topological space $X$ coincide on all sets from some class $\mathcal{U}$ that contains a base $\mathcal{B}$ of the topology $\mathcal{T}$ in $X$ and is closed with respect to finite intersections. Then $\mu=\nu$.

Recall that a Borel measure $\mu$ is called $\tau$-additive on a topological space $X$ if for every increasing net of open sets $(O_i)_{i\in I}$ in $X$ one has the equality
$$|\mu|\bigg(\bigcup_{i\in I}O_i\bigg)=\lim_{i\in I}|\mu|(O_i)$$

The given proof is a little minimalistic:

> Every open set $O\in\mathcal{T}$ can be represented in the form of the union of a net of increasing open sets $O_i$ that are finite unions of sets in $\mathcal{U}$. It is easily seen that $\mu(O_i)=\nu(O_i)$ for all $i\in I$. By the $\tau$-additivity we obtain $\mu(O)=\nu(O)$. Since the two measures coincide an all open sets, they coincide on all Borel sets.

With some help from [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer) I've constructed the net of increasing open sets $(O_i)_{i\in I}$ via the directed set $(I,\subseteq)$, where
$$I:=\{\mathcal{B}_i\subseteq\mathcal{B}\,|\,\mathcal{B}_i\text{ is finite and }\forall B\in\mathcal{B}_i\,:\,B\subseteq O\}. $$
and
$$O_i:=\bigcup_{B\in\mathcal{B}_i}B $$
This yields $O_i\subseteq O_j$ whenever $B_i\subseteq B_j$, $\bigcup_{\mathcal{B}_i\in I}O_i=O$ and every $O_i$ is a finite union of elements of the base $\mathcal{B}$.

Now, I have troubles showing $\mu(O_i)=\nu(O_i)$ for all $\mathcal{B}_i\in I$. Also, I don't see where the assumption that $\mathcal{U}$ is closed with respect to finite intersections is needed.

Any help would be highly appreciated and thank you very much in advance for your efforts!

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inclusion-exclusion:  For any finite set $F$ we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mu\left(\cup_{i\in F} B_i\right)
&=&\sum_{\emptyset \subset J\subseteq F}(-1)^{|J|+1}\mu\left(\cap_{j\in J} B_j\right)\\[5pt]
&=&\sum_{\emptyset \subset J\subseteq F}(-1)^{|J|+1}\nu\left(\cap_{j\in J} B_j\right)\\[5pt]
&=&\nu\left(\cup_{i\in F} B_i\right),
\end{eqnarray*}
where the sum runs over all non-empty subsets $J$ of $F$.
For the second equation you use the fact that $\cal B$ is closed under finite intersections.

Comment: I'd never thought of that, thank you very much!